# Magento 2 : declare new image id with no theme

Tags: magento2, module, product-images, magento2.3

I wish to add a new image id for a custom product widget.

I know I can do this with the file view.xml in my theme but I would like to do this in the Module (app/code/vendor/module).

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-images.html

```
<images module="Magento_Catalog">
    <image id="unique_image_id" type="image_type">
    ...
    </image>
<images/>
```

Is it possible to do this in a module, with no theme ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.
You can create the `etc/view.xml` file in one of your modules and it should be picked up.
Take as example the `etc/view.xml` file from `Magento_Swatch` module.

Comment: Did you find this only in the code ? or is there a reference in the doc ?

Comment: I found it in the code. and a long time ago I tried to create my own entity that supported images and I had to do the same.