# How to add view.xml in custom module for displaying custom gallery in magento 2

Tags: php, layout, magento2.3.4

I am displaying a custom gallery in a custom module and I have to resize my images. I need to know how I can use view.xml in my custom module. If you have a relevant answer then please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You create the custom module and call the your theme `etc/view.xml`. i think may be help you

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/view.xsd">
    <media>
        <images module="VendorName_ModuleName">
            <image id="custom_image" type="custom_image">
                <width>100</width>
                <height>100</height>
            </image>
        </images>
    </media>
    </view>
```

Comment: From where I use image id ? Can you explain more ?

Comment: please refer the link may be help you :- 1. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/272773/magento-2-declare-new-image-id-with-no-theme    2>  https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5381